# Receiving an error "ORA-00904: "ORDERNUMBER": invalid identifier" for php?

Tags: php, html, identification, ora-00904

It says the error code is indentified at line 69 and line 72, which the codes are:

> Line 69: OCI_Execute($stmt);
>
> Line 72: if(OCI_Fetch($stmt)) {

Here is my following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <?php
/* Set oracle user login and password info */
    $dbuser = "..."; /* your [login */
    $dbpass = "..."; /* your oracle access password */
    $db = "SSID";
    $connect = OCILogon($dbuser, $dbpass, $db);

    if (!$connect) {
        echo "An error occurred connecting to the database";
        exit;
    }

// Extract form data
    $book1 = $_REQUEST['book1'] ;
    $price1 = $_REQUEST['price1'] ;
    $quantity1 = $_REQUEST['quantity1'] ;
    $subtotal1 = $_REQUEST['subtotal1'] ;
    $book2 = $_REQUEST['book2'] ;
    $price2 = $_REQUEST['price2'] ;
    $quantity2 = $_REQUEST['quantity2'] ;
    $subtotal2 = $_REQUEST['subtotal2'] ;
    $book3 = $_REQUEST['book3'] ;
    $price3 = $_REQUEST['price3'] ;
    $quantity3 = $_REQUEST['quantity3'] ;
    $subtotal3 = $_REQUEST['subtotal3'] ;
    $book4 = $_REQUEST['book4'] ;
    $price4 = $_REQUEST['price4'] ;
    $quantity4 = $_REQUEST['quantity4'] ;
    $subtotal4 = $_REQUEST['subtotal4'] ;
    $grandtotal = $_REQUEST['grandtotal'] ;

// get the max ID in plants table and allocate $ID+1 for the new record
    $max_id_stmt = "SELECT max(ID) FROM bookorder ";

// check the sql statement for errors and if errors report them
    $stmt = OCIParse($connect, $max_id_stmt);
    if(!$stmt) {
      echo "An error occurred in parsing the sql string.\n";
      exit;
    }
    OCIExecute($stmt);
    $ID =0;

    if(OCIFetch($stmt)) {
      $ID= OCIResult($stmt,1); //return the data from column 1
    }else {
      echo "An error occurred in retrieving book id.\n";
      exit;
    }
    $ID++;

// get the max ID in plants table and allocate $ID+1 for the new record
    $max_OrderNumber_stmt = "SELECT max(OrderNumber) FROM bookorder ";

// check the sql statement for errors and if errors report them
    $stmt = OCIParse($connect, $max_OrderNumber_stmt);
    if(!$stmt) {
      echo "An error occurred in parsing the sql string.\n";
      exit;
    }
    OCI_Execute($stmt);
    $OrderNumber =1111;

    if(OCI_Fetch($stmt)) {
      $OrderNumber= OCIResult($stmt,1); //return the data from column 1
    }else {
      echo "An error occurred in retrieving book order number.\n";
      exit;
    }
    $OrderNumber++;




// Create the SQL statement to add the data. Note: field value should be single quoted '' if VARCHAR2 type.
    $sql = "INSERT INTO plantorder (ID, OrderNumber, plant1, price1, quantity1, subtotal1, plant2, price2, quantity2, subtotal2, plant3, price3, quantity3, subtotal3, plant4, price4, quantity4, subtotal4, grandtotal) VALUES ($ID, '$OrderNumber', '$plant1', '$price1', '$quantity1', '$subtotal1', '$plant2', '$price2', '$quantity2', '$subtotal2', '$plant3', '$price3', '$quantity3', '$subtotal3', '$plant4', '$price4', '$quantity4', '$subtotal4', '$grandtotal')";

// Add the data to the database as a new record
    $stmt = OCIParse($connect, $sql);
    if(!$stmt) {
        echo "An error occurred in parsing the sql string.\n";
        exit;
    }
    OCIExecute($stmt);

    $order_count_sql = "SELECT max(OrderNumber) FROM plantorder";

    $stmt = OCIParse($connect, $order_count_sql);
    if(!$stmt) {
      echo "An error occurred in parsing the sql string.\n";
      exit;
    }
    OCIExecute($stmt);
    $order_count =0;

// retrieve the max order number
    if(OCIFetch($stmt)) {
      $order_count = OCIResult($stmt,1); //return the data from column 1
    }else {
      echo "An error occurred in retrieving order id.\n";
      exit;
    }

    echo("Your order has been received; please quote Order Number #".$order_count." in any correspondence. Thank you.");

 
    ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

i have left out the login and password info just to let you know, that isnt causign the error :) Kind Regards

Comment: Your query failed. It has nothing to do with PHP code but with your database.

Comment: Ohhh okay, thankyou!